# Characterizing the collection of automorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}$ with a binary relation.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can one characterize the collection of automorphisms of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ with the binary relation "$<$"? Or "$>$"? "$=$"? How can we acquire the collection of automorphisms?

Comment: Automorphisms of what structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ are considered? Maybe group or ring?

Comment: @lisyarus: It seems that as an ordered set; which makes more sense that there are no group automorphisms except the identity and conjugation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that really makes much more sence, thank you.

Comment: Kevin, the question is a bit vague. What do you mean by characterize?

Comment: The question is asked after defining isomorphisms between $L_A$ structures (First order logic).

Comment: Perhaps it is asking to characterize the automorphisms of $\mathcal{M} = (\mathbb{Z}, >)$ an $L_A$ structure.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I have given you a hint in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Suppose that $f$ is an automorphism, and $f(0)=n$, what can you tell about $f(1)$ and about $f(-1)$? Show that $f(0)$ decides completely all the values of $f$. Now find a compact and nice way to write $f$.

Comment: $\implies$ $f(1) = n+1$ and $f(-1) =n-1$ so all automorphisms can be written as $f(z) =z+k$, for some $k$ constant. So we can use $<$ to compare the automorphisms to where $f(0)$ has been mapped.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Z=<1>$ or $<-1>$. So all the automorphisms can be created by sending $1$ to $1$ or $-1$. So, there are two automorphisms. So, $Aut(\Bbb Z) \equiv \Bbb Z_2=<-1>$.

Comment: You haven't looked at the comments, have you?

Comment: No, why? Is there any problem?

Comment: Yes. $\Bbb Z$ is not just a ring. It's also a group, it's also an ordered set. It's also a countable set. There are different automorphism groups to different structures.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. Anyway I have given the answer w.r.t group. Lets see what OP comments later.